# Mounting remote filesystem in Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I'd like to SSH from Eclipse Che to a development server I have setup, to edit code on that dev server.  I can see that Che supports SSHing into Che from other machines, but how do I mount via SSHFS or something, a remote directory into Che?

Answer (score 1):

You can do volume mounts in Che - the docs cover it here: https://eclipse.org/che/docs/devops/volume-mounts/index.html

For your scenario you might need to create a mount to your remote server from the server where Che is running then follow the docs instructions to mount that local directory into Che.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to mount container FS? What kind of data is to be mounted? If it's just projects, they are backed up on a host file system.